# Internet Explorer will not launch new windows during test

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm currently having a problems with a window not coming up during tests in Internet Explorer.  I'm using Selenium-RC 2.6.0, programming my tests in C# and launching them using NUnit.

All of my tests work in Firefox and Chrome, but in Internet Explorer 9 when selenium executes a click on a link (The link launches a new window using Javascript) no window comes up.  The window comes up just fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Turn on Popup-blocker is off, Enable Protected Mode is off, Accept all Cookies is on. Windows Firewall is off.  Can anyone think of anything else that could be causing it?  Or if this is a known bug?  I have searched extensively both on SO and Google and haven't turned up any helpful results yet.

Edit: Added code for the element I am attempting to use

```
<a id="supervisor" class="topmenu" onclick="switchSupervisor();"    href="javascript:void(0);">
<span style="font-size: 13px;">
<strong>.</strong>
Supervisor
</span>
</a>
```

---

Thank you for the helpful answers, ironically enough although none of the posted solutions worked my problem was solved through a microsoft update that solved what was apparently a bug or strange functionality in IE that was repaired in the latest update.  I can now easily launch it with a click, or fire event.

Comment: Update: Have been trying to find a workaround the obvious seemed to be to directly call the javascript rather then mess around with the click.  Attempted Selenium.GetEval("this.browserbot.getUserWindow().javaScript()"); but no dice, apparently that's another thing that only works in FF and not IE. Still looking for suggestions!

Comment: Did you try the solution from Deitro?

Comment: In the midst of another project right now but I'll try to get time to test it today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE with Selenium has an annoying bug where elements won't get clicked properly if the link element has any nested elements and no text.

For example:

```
<a id="clickme"><img src="something" /></a>
```

In IE, the following doesn't work:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("clickme")).Click();
```

The workaround is to click the lowest element in the DOM tree under the link element:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("clickme")).FindElement(By.TagName("img")).Click();
//or
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#clickme img")).Click();
```

Comment: I'm using Selenium RC and it looks to me like that is Selenium Webdriver code.  Any chance you know the code for RC?  It occurs to me that running the javascript directly would work as well and am looking for a way now.

Comment: Selenium RC should be very similar. The important part is the selector, I think something like selenium.click("css=#clickme img")

Comment: Thanks for the update, this doesn't solve my problem unfortunately since there are no nested elements, I have posted the code for the tag above.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
Selenium.FireEvent(@"css=a#supervisor", "click")
```